# Refresh sub php page onchange

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'd like to get an interactive block in my page that onchange of one of the 3 search fields only reloads the div 'mydata' and reruns the query with a new filter. I know it probably can be done with ajax but i'm stuck in finding the right piece of code.

Here's my testcode
Main php file users2.php:

```
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
    <script src="../jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    $.ready(function() {
      // create the on change event
      $('#search_name').on('change', function() {
        // get the new information from the server
        $.ajax({
          url: 'users_functions2.php?id=' + $('#search_name').val(),
          success: function(data){
            // this code is run when you get the reply;
            $('#mydata').html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<?PHP

include '../conf/config.inc.php';
include 'users_functions2.php';

?>

</body>
```

And here the include file users_functions2.php:

```
<?php

echo "<div id='mydata'>";

echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>City</th></tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=text placeholder='search' name=search_id</td>";
echo "<td><input type=text placeholder='search' name=search_name</td>";
echo "<td><input type=text placeholder='search' name=search_city</td>";
echo "</tr>";

$sql="select id, name, city from users;";
if (isset($_GET['search_name'])) { $sql .= "WHERE vo_name LIKE \"%".$_GET['search_name']."%\""; }
$res = my_query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['city']."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: 1. Move the config include to the top of `users_functions2.php` 2. grab the parameter using `$_GET['id']` because `id` is the name you're using in the URL

Comment: Ah no the config include is just for the php to find the query and database parameters, query works fine. id was wrong you're right about that, i changed that to search_name. But the issue is that is doesnt reload the users_functions2.php on change of the search_name field.

Comment: Yeah, that's because the file alone won't know what `my_query()` is. The fix is to... do step 1 of my previous comment.

Comment: By including config before functions2, functions2 knows the my_query() function. Like i said the query works fine, it returns data.
I've added a logwrite line into the 2nd file so i can see it only writes the log on initial load and not on a onchange of one of the search fields.

Comment: You are not listening to me. There's is absolutely no need to explain to me what your code does; it's obvious. The query works fine when you request user2, because in that case the db config is included right before you run the query. However when your `$.ajax` subsequently requests *only* user_functions2, that is no longer the case, because you are not including the db config inside user_functions2. I mean, maybe I'm missing something, and it won't work right away after you do the change I suggested, but I don't understand why you don't even try it?

Comment: Sorry, i was listening and now i follow your thought. I should have said i tried it to be sure after you first mentioned it and it doesn't make any difference.
If config was the issue i would expect an error in the log about function not found.
I added in users_functions2.php now a line 
trigger_error("here i am", E_USER_NOTICE);
So i can see if it even runs the file and it only does it on initial load. I should say my php knowlegde is ok but javascript isn't, i found the java function as some example but that is most certain not the right way of doing it.

Comment: Ok, so let's first make sure the table file works as intended. You can easily test it by putting its URL directly in the browser's address bar, like http://localhost/project/user_functions2.php?search_name=london What do you see if you do that? (also, tiny unrelated issue: you should move `<div id='mydata'>` to the main file, or you'll put that same div inside itself over and over again)

Comment: Ok, moved the div tags around the inclusion now.
Running the functions file now works fine, it needed an extra space before the WHERE part. Tried running the main file again, no change in there.

Comment: I didn't even look at the query; you need to remove the `;` after `users`. Also, you can inspect the ajax request in the browser's dev tools; check the console (turn on `xhr` if it's off)

Comment: Yep, ; was already gone.
I used chrome and firefox, i believe the option in chrome is to log xmlhttprequests, anyhow, enabled in both browsers, set level to verbose but console stays empty on load and on onchange.

Comment: Like I said, you need to turn on `xhr`s so you see the request kicked off by `$.ajax()` in addition to potential console outputs. In Firefox, check the bar at the top of the console tab; there's a bunch of buttons on the right. Click "XHR" so it's turned on.

Comment: Like i said, i enabled it in both browers and nothing is returned on refresh or on onchange

Comment: Right, add `id="search_name"` to the `<input>` so jQuery can find it.

Comment: Yes, thought of that as well and played with it. Adding the id did not do anyting at first.
When i changed the first script line "$.ready(function() {" in to "$(document).ready(function() {" It reruns the query onchange. But of course it only works once, on the 2nd onchange nothing happens.

Comment: It's because the input is in the part you replace, so the input that had the onchange listener assigned is gone and replaced by one without it. Give me a sec.

Comment: I've put a working version online here: https://github.com/khrismuc/ronald

Comment: Thank you Chris! So to recap, the main issue for not starting the ajax was the missing (document) object in the start of the function and the missing input id. And the not working a second time is fixed by moving the inputs to the main page.
Here i can work with, again thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hope Chris is ok with this, i'd like my question being answered with a working example:

File 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // create the on change event
    $('#search_name').on('change', function() {
      // get the new information from the server
      $.ajax({
        url: 'users_functions2.php?search_name=' + $('#search_name').val(),
        success: function(data){
          // this code is run when you get the reply;
          $('#mydata').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>City</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th><input type=text placeholder='search' name=search_id></th>
          <th><input type=text placeholder='search' id='search_name' name=search_name></th>
          <th><input type=text placeholder='search' name=search_city></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="mydata">
        <?PHP
        include 'users_functions2.php';
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>
```

File 2:

```
<?php

include '../conf/config.inc.php';

$sql="SELECT id, `name`, city FROM users";

$search_name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search_name');

if ($search_name) {
    $sql .= " WHERE vo_name LIKE \"%$search_name%\""; 
}

$res = my_query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    extract($row);
    echo "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td>$city</td></tr>";
}

?>
```